# access hadoop intermediate map output files

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Is it possible to access or read map intermediate output files i.e. sequential file- file.out ?
I want to read a file.out file. I used approach mentioned in this link, http://hadooptutorial.info/hadoop-sequence-files-example/   ,
but it says that file.out is not a sequential file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the output of the mapper use the following configuration argument while running the job

```
-Dmapreduce.job.reduces = 0
```

It will set the number of reducers to 0, leading to 0 partitioners and only mappers result will be displayed in output directory.